# How to Add Table Prefix In Entity Framework Code First Globally?

Tags: entity-framework

I want to add all tables in the database with a prefix like 'pe_', then the mapping between a class and a table will be like this: Category(pe_Category), Product(pe_Product), etc.

I know that with one single map, i can do like this:

```
[Table("pe_Category")]
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't like it cause there maybe have hundreds of entities.

So I'm finding a way to add the prefix globally, just like this:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}

// Global config, will affect all entities
table.Name = "pe_" + Class.TypeName ;
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Now I've find a solution with entity framework 6 alpha:

1) Create a class named "DefaultTableConvention":

```
public class DefaultTableConvention
: IConfigurationConvention<Type, EntityTypeConfiguration>
{
    public void Apply(
        Type type,
        Func<EntityTypeConfiguration> configuration)
    {            
        configuration().ToTable("PE_" + type.Name);
    }
}
```

2) In the DbContext, add the code below:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<DefaultTableConvention>();
    }
```

And that's all, It will affect all entities added in the DbContext.  Detail:http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions

**Update:**
Now with EF6, there's an easier way, which is called "Lightweight Configuration", here's the code:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Types().Configure(entity => entity.ToTable("PE" + entity.ClrType.Name));
    }
```

Comment: Would this also stop the name being pluralised?

Answer (score 14):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Entities().Configure(entity 
      => entity.ToTable("PE" + entity.ClrType.Name));
 }
```

only works on *ef6-beta-1*; Microsoft changed Entities to Types from *ef6-rc1*

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/08/21/ef6-release-candidate-available.aspx#10444012

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Types().Configure(entity 
      => entity.ToTable("PE" + entity.ClrType.Name));
 }
```

Comment: I have tried your second code example, but I get errors if I leave off the 'base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);' However, if I put that in, either before OR after the types configuration line, my tables don't change names in the scaffolding when I Add-Migration.I'm trying to change the name of the AspNet tables to add a new prefix. They just stay the same though.

Answer (score 10):

This works with EF Core 3.1+

Add a reference to the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`.

```
foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
   entity.SetTableName("PE" + entity.GetTableName());
}
```

Comment: To get this working with EF core 3.1 you need to add a package reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`

Answer (score 3):

This works for EF Core 2.0+

```
foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{                        
    entity.Relational().TableName = "PE" + entity.Relational().TableName;
}
```

Comment: This could really use additional context like what is in @Bowyee's answer.