# Global table prefix with Entity Framework 7 (rc1)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We're using the RC1 release of ASP.NET 5 with the new Entity Framework 7 and I'd like to have table names in the database to be prefixed with the name of the namespace in which the model lives.

I know how to do this with in the previous version of Entity Framework (thanks to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633015/how-to-add-table-prefix-in-entity-framework-code-first-globally)) but I can't figure out how to do the same in the new version. I went through the docs, Googled it and poked my head in the source code, to no avail.

What I do in EF6:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Types().Configure(entity => entity.ToTable($"{entity.ClrType.Namespace?.Replace('.', '-')}_{entity.ClrType.Name}s"));

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

How can I do the same with EF7? Is this one of the things that aren't in there yet maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it at the end of `OnModelCreating` by manipulating the model directly:

```
foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    entity.Relational().TableName =
        $"{entity.ClrType.Namespace?.Replace('.', '-')}_{entity.ClrType.Name}s";
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly. Changes the table names from Idenity too but I suppose that's just an easy thing to change in that loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As of today, Dic, 9th, 2015, the EF7 custom conventions issue is still open:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/214

If you visit that link, you can drill into more details.

Comment: Yes, I see. Well then I suppose we could just do it manually by using the  `[Table("Namespace_Foo")]` attribute above the classes, at least for the time being.