# Are the names of my DbSet properties used by Entity Framework code-first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Given class `animal` when using Entity Framework:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<animal> abc_animals { get; set; }
}
```

Does the property name `abc_animals` matter? I was hoping this would control the table name without having to use annotations but apparently not. It's annoying if I want to prefix all my table-names with the same string.

Comment: Guess this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633015/how-to-add-table-prefix-in-entity-framework-code-first-globally

Comment: Yeah that's very cool... but orginal question stands, does my property name make any difference at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source : [Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/167)

> In past pre-release of EF Core, the table name for an entity was the
>   same as the entity class name. In RC2 we now use the name of the DbSet
>   property. If no DbSet property is defined for the given entity type,
>   then the entity class name is used.

**Table Naming Convention Changes**

> A significant functional change we took in RC2 was to use the name of
>   the DbSet property for a given entity as the table name it
>   maps to, rather than just the class name. You can read more about this
>   change in the related announcement issue.

Comment: Is this for upcoming EF7?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Already released : https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html#table-naming-convention-changes

Comment: Ah OK this was released in the RC, but it is still _in_ RC status. Isn't this a breaking change when EF7 is released, for any project which automatically updates to v7?

Comment: @Mr.Boy The previous link in the comments have the update strategy stated for table names when moving from RC1 to RC2. Sorry but I don't really have any additional information on this matter as I stopped using EF since a while.