# Prefix AND pluralise table names in EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I came across this neat feature: [How to Add Table Prefix In Entity Framework Code First Globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633015/how-to-add-table-prefix-in-entity-framework-code-first-globally)

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //prefix "PE" on table name
        modelBuilder.Types().Configure(entity => entity.ToTable("PE" + entity.ClrType.Name));
    }
```

But this loses the pluralisation functionality which I want. I can't just append `"s"` because a type name like "puppy" should pluralise to "puppies" not "puppys".

Answer (score 1):

You can call the pluralization service that the underlying EF convention is using:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //prefix "PE" on table name
    var pluralizationService = DbConfiguration.DependencyResolver.GetService<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Pluralization.IPluralizationService>();
    modelBuilder.Types().Configure(entity => entity.ToTable("PE" + pluralizationService.Pluralize(entity.ClrType.Name)));
}
```

And don't forget to add `using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution;`